# TreeView Items Serialization

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, serialization, treeview

I have a TreeView which has new Items added to it when a certain event is called.

I 'd like to, whenever a certain "save" event is called, get the current items of the TreeView, store them and then serialize them to make them available for loading in future instances of the application.

How can I acomplish that?

Note that the question is not so much as to how to serialize the data but more as to what data to actually serialize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all you need to serialize. You basically serialize the `Items` property:

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(destinatioFile, tree.Items.Cast<WhateverYourTypeIs>().ToList());
```

Comment: The Nodes property seems that it is not available. Do I need a specific namespace? Note that I use WPF and not windows forms.